# Simple login not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a login for my app. The problem is when I hit the button, nothing happens. I think I have everything correct. I made it where if you type in the Username field: "parents" and the password: "!saints" it should send you to the announcements layout.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class LoginWorker extends Activity {

     Button login;
     EditText user, pass;
     ToggleButton repass;
     TextView invail;

    public boolean savelogin = false;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bloginf);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernametf);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordtf);
        invail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invalidinfo);
        repass = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.rememberlogintb);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String u = user.getText().toString();
        String p = pass.getText().toString();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(u.equalsIgnoreCase("parents")){
                    if(p.equals("!saints")){
                        if(repass.isChecked()){
                            savelogin = true;
                                                   setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
                        }
                    }else if(!repass.isChecked()){
            savelogin = false;
            setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
        }
    }if(!user.getText().equals("parents")){
        invail.setText("Invalid Username and / or Password!");
    }if(!pass.getText().equals("!saints")){
        invail.setText("Invalid Username and / or Password!");
    }
} 
}); 
}    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would add System.out (or) debug pointers to make sure which point logic is failing.

Comment: try debugging and check if he steps into

Comment: Did you delete some code? I don't see how you could ever see the login form.

Comment: Where is the first setcontentview? O.o

Answer (score 2):

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
String u = user.getText().toString();
String p = pass.getText().toString();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(u.equalsIgnoreCase("parents")){
            if(p.equals("!saints")){
                if(repass.isChecked()){
                    savelogin = true;
                    setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
                }
            }else if(!repass.isChecked()){
    savelogin = false;
    setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
}
```

should be:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     String u = user.getText().toString();
     String p = pass.getText().toString();
        if(u.equalsIgnoreCase("parents")){
            if(p.equals("!saints")){
                if(repass.isChecked()){
                    savelogin = true;
                    setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
                }
            }else if(!repass.isChecked()){
    savelogin = false;
    setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, when I hit the login button, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing a copy of the contents of your EditTexts right after they're created, before anything is typed into them, and that's what you're using in your click handler. Change your onClickListener to read directly from the EditTexts whenever the button/click handler is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.layout.announcements);`
This line should be the First line in your on create method.

```
 String u = user.getText().toString();
 String p = pass.getText().toString();
```

This two line should be in your onClick Method